# make google maps zoom fit to marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i have a map, and there is a marker , i want to fit zoom on it, this is what i've tried.

```
var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
agentMap.setCenter(mapCenter);
agent_marker.setPosition(mapCenter);
```

also this

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend(agent_marker.getPosition());
agentMap.fitBounds(bounds);
```

both of them didn't work ,the marker is on the top corner , i want the marker on the center of the map

Comment: Sounds like the size of the map-container  is unknown when you set the position/bounds. Please post more code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the marker in the map so that it is visible follow the steps:

1) Set desired zoom of the map at which you want to display to the map. Suppose 15 here

```
 map.setZoom(15);
```

2) Then you just need to set center of the map to the position of the marker as

```
map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
```

---

If you want the map to automatically fit to the marker, you can declare a bounds variable and the apply this bound on the map.

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```